# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 Model not staying on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

These are all my linked Javascript files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/holder/holder.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/assets/js/application.js"></script>
```

These are all my linked CSS files:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> 
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

And here is my Model:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that when I click on the button to launch the Model it only pops up on my screen for 1 second then it disappears. For some reason it's not staying on the screen.

Comment: And by the way I purposly did not add the modal.js because I already have the bootstrap.js and I believe you can only add 1 of them from what I read in order for the model to work.

Comment: `bootstrap.js` contains all the `bootstrap*.js` files you included and  `bootstrap.min.css` is just a compressed version of `bootstrap.css`

Comment: regaurdless if those files are attached or not it doesn't fix the problem. I dont know why but the model only stays on the screen for 1 second then it disappear.

Answer (score 1):

hey it is working fine for me. [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/gjqac/1/)

more over you only need to add any one of  `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css`.

actually `bootstrap.min.css` is just a compressed version of `bootstrap.css`.

you don't need to add all javascript files.

#### a basic example:

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> 

<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>

<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

to test it, just copy the above code into a text-editor and save it as `**.html`, then just open it on some browser

Comment: I do have jquery.js already linked as you can see. If I add the model.js and I click Launch Model, the model will appear only for 1 second and go away but the black background that pops up stays. So the model information and white boxes and what not disappears and the black background is still there.

Comment: @LucasSantos do you checked the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/gjqac/1/) or did you checked the above code, ie just copy the above code into a text-editor and save it as **.html, then just open it on some browser. when i checked both ways are worked fine.. please note that `bootstrap.js` contains all the `bootstrap*.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem. I needed to delete

```
<script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Guess you can't include the bootstrap.min.js

Comment: `bootstrap.min.js` is just a compressed version of `bootstrap.js`. ie spaces are deleted and it is a single line txt file.